# What is WSO2 authorization and how it's different from Oauth?

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have some idea on Oauth, it's an open standard framework which helps in Authorization process by creating a token and using that to access some resources. 
I googled a bit about WSO2 I understood that it provides service oriented solutions

Recently my senior said that we need to move to WSO2 . I didn't understand what he meant by that. So I did some searching again and I found that WSO2 has an Identity Server which helps in authorization.

I suggested that we can use OAuth for authorization. But my seniors insisted saying we have to use WSO2.

So I want to know what is WSO2 Authorization and how its different from OAuth?

Answer (score 3):

WSO2 IS is identity and entitlement management server. It facilitates security and identity management of enterprise web applications, services, and APIs and carries support for OpenID, Information Cards, XACML, and SAML 2.0

WSO2 IS support Oauth2 too. Please refer.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/Managing+OAuth

http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/08/wso2-oauth-20-playground-with-wso2.html

Please refer

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/WSO2+Identity+Server+Documentation

for other supported authorization mechanisams.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use WSO2 IS as for authorization. Further you can use Oauth with WSO2 IS.

Following posts will be help full.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/WSO2+Identity+Server+Documentation

[2] http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/08/wso2-oauth-20-playground-with-wso2.html

[3] http://blog.facilelogin.com/2012/08/wso2-oauth-20-playground-with-wso2.html